# Ошибка при билде с Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel

При попытке билда образа проекта командой `docker build -t myapp .` с Dockerfile возникает сообщение об ошибке:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 84.99 kB
Step 1/17: FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
Error parsing reference: "microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

Пробовал обновлять пакеты, перезапускать Docker но все было безуспешно. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: они переименовывали репозитории возможно сейчас оно доступно тут mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.2, но версия 2.2 уже не подерживается, лучше перейти хотя бы на 3.1

Comment: @ExplodingKitten благодарю! ошибка исчезла, но на ее месте оказалась х509 ошибка: certificate signed by unknown authority, я до этого вроде ставил сертификаты, с этой ошибкой также не первый день вожусь и все не могу нормально решить, что нужно сделать чтобы избавиться от нее?